# Propagating HealthKit Delete to back end

Tags: ios, xamarin, healthkit, hkobserverquery

Hope this question doesn't sound too silly, but I haven't been able to find a solution yet.  I'm currently writing an app using Xamarin that integrates with HealthKit.  Data stored in HK is periodically synced to a server. This is done through an HKAnchoredObjectQuery that pulls Food Correlations.

Since the Data is pulled periodically there is the scenario that between syncs, a user might delete a value in HealthKit.  That delete needs to be propagated back to the server on the next sync.

My initial thought was to do this with an Observer Query.

My **Question** is: Using an Observer Query for HealthKit, is there a way to determine if the action that triggered the query is a delete action?

```
public void CheckForDelete (Subject subject)
    {
        var sampleType = HKObjectType.GetCorrelationType (HKCorrelationTypeKey.IdentifierFood);
        var predicate = HKQuery.GetPredicateForSamples (NSDate.DistantPast, NSDate.Now, HKQueryOptions.None);
        var observerQuery = new HKObserverQuery (sampleType, predicate, (query, completion, error ) => {
            //...Determine if action was a Delete
            //Code to delete on backend

            completion();
        });

        HealthKitStore.ExecuteQuery (observerQuery);
    }
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this yet? I'm facing the same issue and I think there's no easy way to track deleted samples. I think I need to check if the samples still exist in HealthApp and delete them manually.

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.  I tried to create a separate observer query for each element to listen for deletes and then trigger a database delete when that observer query is called but that didn't behave as i thought it would.  It also created a background query thread for every element (which could be in the hundreds).

As far as i can tell there really is no way to detect whether healthkit data was deleted from a separate app. Hopefully somebody figures it out though!

Comment: The way I did was saving the entries to my own database, and when the `observerQuery` hits I call a `sampleQuery` to get the actual samples. That done, I iterate thought the samples and check what was added and what was deleted. I created a column `healthUUID` in my database to save the identification of the `Health` samples, that way, it is easy to track differences between my database and `health app`.

Comment: if you wish to do something similar, let me know and I can share the code.

Comment: hey guys, have you discovered how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 9, `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` has been modified to report deleted objects.